# How to run a Spark Standalone master on Kubernetes that will use the Kubernetes Cluser Manager to start workers

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I have an application that currently uses Standalone Mode locally to use spark functionality via the `SparkContext`. We are not using spark-submit to upload our jobs, we are running our application in a container on kubernetes so we would like to take advantage of the dynamic scheduling that kubernetes provides to run the jobs.

We started out looking for a helm chart to create stand alone cluster running on kubernetes similar to how you would have run a standalone cluster on machines ( vms or actual machines ) a few years ago and came across the following

https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/spark

Issues:

- very old instances of spark
- not using the containers provided by spark
- this setup wastes a bunch of resources if you need to have large worker nodes reserved and running all the time regardless of your need

Next we started looking at the spark-operator approach here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator

Issues:

- Doesn't support the way we interact with spark, takes the approach that all the apps are standalone apps that are pushed to the cluster to run
- No longstanding master that allows us to take advantage of cached resources in the cluster

Along this journey we discovered that spark now supports a kubernetes cluster manager ( similar to the way it does with yarn, mesos ) so we are looking that this might be the best approach, but this still does not provide a standalone master that would allow for the in memory caching.  I have looked to see if there was a way that I could get the `org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master` to start and use the 
`org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesClusterManager`

So I guess what I'm trying to ask is does anyone have any experience in trying to run a Standalone Master, that would use the kubernetes backend such as "KubernetesClusterManager" in order to have the worker nodes dynamically created as pods and running executors while having a permanent Standalone Master that would allow a SparkContext to connect to it remotely in client mode.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? It seems most people use spark-submit and only a few create dedicated apps using SparkContext.

Comment: We are currently also trying to get something in place like your approach. We would like to have a running master where we can connect with notebooks, open a interactive session, and run some queries. The master then spins up executor pods depending on the config from the spark session if needed.